# handling large non-sparse matrices for computing SVD

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, large-data, svd, eigenvalue

I have a large matrix (right now about 450000 x 50, might be even larger) that I want to compute its SVD decomposition. The matrix isn't sparse and numpy can't seem to handle it and exits with MemoryError.

I tried using np.float16 and it didn't help. python's table package can't seem to help either (since I need to use the whole matrix later to find eigenvalues).

Do any of you have an idea how can I compute and use massive matrices?

Comment: Please post the code that you've tried so far, it will be much easier to help you that way.

Comment: A common approach to dealing with such problems is *sketching*. One example is approximating your matrix by sampling some of the columns, and then computing the SVD on this smaller matrix (after scaling appropriately).  [This](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.4061) is perhaps the most well known introduction to the topic. If you want a more in depth explanation you could try posting to the math stackexchange.

Comment: For now I used a quick solution by applying feature selection (over the rows). I'll try sketching if my solution won't work properly. @tch Thank you!